# AngularJS ES6 import angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to import angular-translate in angularjs 1.5.3 project using ES6
when I try `import angular-translate;` it doesn't import any thing from the angular translate module, I tried also `import pascalprecht.translate from 'angular-translate';` but that generates a syntax error as it doesn't accept the `.` or `-` in the module name.
did any one know the correct way to import `angular-translate` in my project.
thank you in advance.

Comment: `import pascalprecht from 'path/to/angular-translate.js';` Import statements take a filepath. You can also only import something that has been exported, so you can't import an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can import it either using `import 'angular-translate';` or `import pascalprecht from 'angular-translate';`

Answer (score 0):

In you app modules, just add the module : 'pascalprecht.translate', to the imported module.

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'pascalprecht.translate',
         //......
      ])
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try for this artical:

Here i have wrote an article, How we can use **translate filter in ECMAscript6**.

```
<p> Translate With Pipe: <strong>{{ ‘hello world’ | translate }}</strong></p>
```

[click here to read article regarding this](https://medium.com/@kunvar/angular-2-internationalization-49954cb73add)